# Redirecting to a page requiring session cookies in bottle

Tags: python, bottle

I am looking for advice on how to redirect to a page requiring session cookies in bottle. I want to allow users to, given the correct username and password for a given service, be automatically re-directed to this external service logged in.

I have a function that is able to login server side, get a redirection URL and session cookies for auth.

```
 with requests.session() as s:
    r = s.post("https://someservice.com/Account/LogOn",
               data=payload)

    redirect_object = {'url':r, 'session':s}
    return redirect_object
```

When I try to redirect using

```
bottle.redirect(redirect_object['url'])
```

I clearly get sent to the login page instead of to the homepage as a logged in user as I do not have the session information in my browser.

How do I pass this session information when being redirected to the homepage? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The response from `post` is not a url, it's an object of type `requests.models.Response`.

`bottle.redirect` takes a url (string), not a `requests.models.Response` object.

If your application is simple enough, perhaps you can just get away with hard coding your post-login page:

```
bottle.redirect('http://example.com/home')
```

Otherwise, you should consult the login service's API docs to see how to extract the url from their response. E.g., perhaps they return json, which you'll need to decode, that contains a "url" field.

```
resp = s.post(...)
resp_dict = json.loads(resp.content)
bottle.redirect(resp_dict['post_auth_url'])
```